# What does this mean? : fatal error: attempt to evaluate editor placeholder

Tags: swift3, xcode8.2

Full Error :

fatal error: attempt to evaluate editor placeholder: file /var/folders/d0/q4xnv1gd5rs_j7cx8jv8qv1h0000gn/T/./lldb/30026/playground364.swift, line 531

This happened while running a 500+ line Swift playground using XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002).

```
struct Nest : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    var eggCount : Int
    init(integerLiteral eggCount : Int) {
        self.eggCount = eggCount
    }
    init (_ eggCount : Int) {
        self.init(integerLiteral : eggCount)
    }
}

func describeNest(_ nest : Nest) {
    print("This nest has \(nest.eggCount) eggs")
}

let nest = Nest(6)
describeNest(nest)
```

The final line here is line 531.

Comment: Without knowing the code in line 531 nobody can answer that.

Comment: Show us the code on line 531. Also try Cmd + shift + K

Comment: Reload fixed it. Code was unrelated.